# How to plot graph type='h' in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm wondering how to plot in ggplot2 something like this:
let's say I've got two numeric vectors:
`time <-c(1,3,4,6,9,10,12), n.censor<-c(0,0,1,4,0,3,1)`
and I'd like to plot:
`plot(n.censor~time,type='h')`

How to achieve something like this in ggplot2 ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a "histogram" is the look you want, but the data are coded as if they're for a bar graph, since they are already aggregated. As such, your stat will be "identity". 
Here's some code to use for ggplot() :

```
 # first put your vectors into a data.frame
 df <- data.frame(time, n.censor)
 # plot
 ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=n.censor))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")

 # or alternatively, with the histogram layer:
 ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=n.censor))+
    geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Unfortunaetly, I have already tried both ways, everytime I get this warning: `Warning message:
position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect `. And the output graph is wrong.

Comment: the code works for the small amount of data that you provided. Are you trying to do something more complicated?

Comment: Yes, I have much bigger data set, it's from survival analysis. Thanks for your effort. Accidentally, I found solution in another post. This type of plots are called: needle plot and I wasnt aware of that,